# Home-brew installation fails on High Sierra

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to install Homebrew on a Mac mini with High Sierra v10.13. I run the following command as instructed:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

The terminal informs me that it will install brew and asks password, but it eventually fails and shows the following message:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)
==> Installing 
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/softwareupdate -i 
Software Update Tool
: No such update
No updates are available.
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/rm -f /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, so I am posting this here to help anyone in pain !

The command **brew doctor** tells me that **some installed formulae are missing dependencies**.

After doing the command **brew upgrade**, I get the error for some dependencies (below is the example for openjdk) :

```
configure: error: No xcodebuild tool and no system framework headers found, use --with-sysroot or --with-sdk-name to provide a path to a valid SDK
/private/tmp/openjdk-20200219-89506-1wim844/jdk13u-jdk-13.0.2+8/build/.configure-support/generated-configure.sh: line 82: 5: Bad file descriptor
configure exiting with result code 1

These open issues may also help:
Migrate formulae to depend on `openjdk`.
```

**Here is how I solved this :**

- sudo xcode-select -r
- Edit and set the date of your Mac as October 1st, 2019
- sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
- sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
- brew upgrade

**And it worked !** (i am using a iMac mid2011 with MacOS Sierra)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it with help from a senior programmer.
The error was due to absence of Xcode Command Line Interface even though it was showing present in Xcode>>preference>>Location>>Command Line Tools.

So, I had to manually download the Command Line Interface dmg file from my Apple Accounts download section and install it.